# Including standard boiler-plate on opening a new latex file

Tags: files, find-file

Most of my \LaTeX files have the same boiler plate code, so I would like Emacs to automatically insert this boiler-plate whenever I open a fresh, blank \LaTeX file.

In particular, I would like to include the following preamble.

```
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex} 
    \setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
    \addbibresource{References.bib}
    \author{A.U.Thor}
    \date{}

    \begin{document}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}


    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

How should I modify my `.emacs` file to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Emacs Wiki page [Automatic File Headers](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutomaticFileHeaders).

That page mentions mode [Auto Insert](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode), which is part of vanilla Emacs, and it describes libraries [`header2.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutomaticFileHeaders#toc2) and [`file-template.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/file-template.el).